# Spring Data JPA - How to find by param with underscore

Tags: spring, repository, spring-data-jpa

Here is my model:

```
public class Log {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String project;
    private String test_no;

    // Constructor, getters and setters.
}
```

How can I add a `findBy` query which allows me to finding an element by its `test_no` value? I have tried those method headers but they don't work:

```
List<Log> findByTest_No(String test_no);
```

The error that my STS reports is: Invalid delivery query! No property test found in type Log!

```
List<Log> findByTest_no(String test_no);
```

The error that my STS reports is: Invalid delivery query! No property test found in type Log!

```
List<Log> findByTestno(String test_no);
```

The error that my STS reports is: Invalid derived query! No property testno found for type Log! Did you mean 'test_no'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `_` is a special character which separates properties names

> ...  it is possible for the algorithm to select the wrong property ... To resolve this ambiguity you can use \_ inside your method name to manually define traversal points ...

[Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

So it can't find `test` field in `Log` class.

Try to use:

```
@Query("select log from Log log where log.test_no = ?1")
List<Log> findByTestNo(String testNo);
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use `private String test_no;` You may use `private String testNo;` Spring automatically understand that you are binding `test_no` column in the database.  Also you can use

```
@Column(name = "test_no")
private String testNo;
```

After this changes you can execute queries, mentioned in your question without any custom sql.

```
List<Log> findByTestNo(String testNo);
```